# c# - how to validate sharepoint list column against ValidationFormula programmatically

Tags: 2013, validation

I need to validate a string that user submit against `SPField.ValidationFormula` while adding new record to custom list in c#.

Line to add new record is

`SPListItem item = mylist.Items.Add();`

I have formula in

`column.ValidationFormula`

and my string to validate is in this variable

`mystringtovalidate`

How can I validate `mystringtovalidate` against `column.ValidationFormula` then if is valid I'll do `item.Update();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following pattern

```
try {
    item.Update();
}
catch(SPListDataValidationException ex) {
    //ex.Message
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistdatavalidationexception_members(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: is there a manual way to validate it? reason is I don't want to update it yet since I check many other things that sharepoint does not then update my record. If I do this, it will add record with several empty fields when current column formula validates.

Comment: in that case you should perform your validation first then do the `item.update()`. Else I think you should end up parsing the Formula & then validating.

Comment: is it possible to catch errors for more than one field? let say I have 3 columns with different validationformula. will this try catch give me all 3 errors so I can use them? I'm new to all this c# and sharepoint so sorry :/

Comment: I think so, you can check the Exception Message Property. You can test it and confirm.

Comment: I think it will give the first validation error it encounters not all of them.

Comment: ok seems `ex.FieldFailures` returns ALL errors ancountered. I'll check in detail and try to change my approach and implement this. I'll let you know and accept your answer if it works.